# `ssh foo "<command/>"` not loading remote aliases?

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, bashrc, login-script

summary: Why does this fail

```
$ ssh foo 'R --version | head -n 1'
bash: R: command not found
```

but this succeeds

```
$ ssh foo 'grep -nHe 'bashrc' ~/.bash_profile'
/home/me/.bash_profile:3:# source the users .bashrc if it exists
/home/me/.bash_profile:4:if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
/home/me/.bash_profile:5:  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
$ ssh foo 'grep -nHe "\WR\W" ~/.bashrc'
/home/me/.bashrc:118:alias R='/share/linux86_64/bin/R'
$ ssh foo '/share/linux86_64/bin/R --version | head -n 1'
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
```

? details:

I am a (rootless) user on 2 clusters. One uses environment modules, so any given server on that cluster can provide (via `module add`) pretty much the same resources. The other cluster, on which I must also unfortunately work, has servers managed individually, so I get in the habit of doing, e.g.,

```
EXEC_NAME='whatever'
for S in 'foo' 'bar' 'baz' ; do
  ssh ${SERVER} "${EXEC_NAME} --version"
done
```

This works fine for packages installed normally/consistently, but often (for reasons unknown to me) packages are not: e.g. (compare alias below to alias above),

```
$ ssh bar 'R --version | head -n 1'
bash: R: command not found
$ ssh bar 'grep -nHe 'bashrc' ~/.bash_profile'
/home/me/.bash_profile:3:# source the users .bashrc if it exists
/home/me/.bash_profile:4:if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
/home/me/.bash_profile:5:  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
$ ssh bar 'grep -nHe "\WR\W" ~/.bashrc'
/home/me/.bashrc:118:alias R='/share/linux/bin/R'
$ ssh bar '/share/linux86_64/bin/R --version | head -n 1'
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
```

Using aliases copes well with these install differences when I interactively shell into the server, but fails when I try to script ssh commands (as above); i.e.,

```
# interactively
$ ssh foo
...
foo> R --version
```

calls my alias for `R` on remote host=`foo`, but

```
# scripting
$ ssh foo 'R --version'
```

doesn't.  What do I need to do to make `ssh foo "<command/>"` load my aliases on the remote host?

Comment: Interesting. Aliases seem to be ignoered entirely. Even explicitly defining an alias per `ssh foo 'alias ll="ls -l"; ll'` won't work.

Comment: Please don't update your title to change the status.  Use the Accept/upvote features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `bash` manpage:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt  (see  the  description  of
>          shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

You need to `shopt -s expand_aliases` in your remote `.bashrc`s, and check that those  `.bashrc` are processed when non-interactive; the default `.bashrc` for your distribution may include a check to terminate early when non-interactive, e.g. Ubuntu uses:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Comment: Note remote `.bashrc` had `[[ "$-" != *i* ]] && return`

Answer (score 2):

Andrew's answer explained the reason. I only give one more solution:

In stead of using `aliases`, use their `function equivalents`.

For example:

In stead of using:
`alias ll='ls -lah'`

Use this:

`function ll{
    ls -lah "$@"
}`